'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial' error on ArduinoIDE
im new to Arduino Dev etc, and i have a project with Micro:Bit (v2). Sadly, when i try to use bluetooth with the Adafruit_Microbit library (ble_uartdemo), i got this error :
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino: In function 'void setup()':
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:27:12: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
   microbit.BTLESerial.setLocalName("microbit");
            ^
~\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:28:12: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
   microbit.BTLESerial.begin();
            ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino: In function 'void loop()':
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:35:12: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
   microbit.BTLESerial.poll();
            ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino: In function 'void forward()':
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:45:16: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
   if (microbit.BTLESerial && Serial) {
                ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:47:18: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
     if (microbit.BTLESerial.available()) {
                  ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:48:29: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
       Serial.write(microbit.BTLESerial.read());
                             ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:59:16: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
       microbit.BTLESerial.write(buffer, idx);
                ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino: In function 'void loopback()':
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:67:16: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
   if (microbit.BTLESerial) {
                ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:69:29: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
     while ((byte = microbit.BTLESerial.read()) > 0) {
                             ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:70:18: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
         microbit.BTLESerial.write(byte);
                  ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino: In function 'void spam()':
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:77:16: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
   if (microbit.BTLESerial) {
                ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:78:14: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
     microbit.BTLESerial.print(millis());
              ^
~\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202431-12204-ufdmrr.i4qn\ble_uartdemo\ble_uartdemo.ino:79:14: error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'
     microbit.BTLESerial.println(" tick-tacks!");
              ^

exit status 1

Compilation error: 'class Adafruit_Microbit' has no member named 'BTLESerial'

So as you can see the error is about BTLESerial no being inside Adafruit_Microbit.
I have the lastest version of Arduino IDE, AdaFruit, and Micro:Bit 2.21. (I have SoftDevice set to "none" because i didnt manage to get it working, so i just put the .hex file into the microbit and it seems to be working.)
Thanks !!!
